# Integration by parts from a physics textbook

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I am trying to understand a formula derivation from a physics textbook, and could get the result up until the last step. The author mentions you just need to integrate by parts, however, I'm not able to get his results.

More specifically, I want to show that

$\int_l^d\int_r^dsu(s)ds dr = \int_l^dr(r-l)u(r)dr $,

and $u(s)$ is a potential such that

$u(s)=\int_s^df(s')ds' \ , \ \ \displaystyle \frac{du}{ds}=-f(s) \ , \ \ u(s\ge d)=0 \ , \ \ f(s\ge d)=0  $.

Can anyone help me in understanding that?

Comment: Have you tried evaluating both sides for some specific function $u$, for example $u(s)=d-s$? It's messy and I haven't checked my arithmetic but I don't think I get the same on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another point-of-view is to see this as a change in integration order à la Fubini. Then
$$
\iint_{l<r<s<d}su(s)\,ds\,dr=\iint_{l<r<s<d}su(s)\,dr\,ds
=\int_l^d\int_l^s su(s)dr\,ds=\int_l^d(s-l)su(s)\,ds
$$
In the second form the integrand is constant for the inner integal, so resolves to the difference of the endpoints. There is no difference if the fineal integration variable is $r$ or $s$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I thought it had something to do with changing the integration order but because r was one of the inner integral limits this change was not possible. I just don't quite get how it's possible to change the limits like that, do you recommend any textbook or source so I can look it up in more detail?

Comment: The $(r,s)$ integration domain is a rectangular triangle, with the hypotenuse on the diagonal. The change is from slicing it horizontally to vertically (or vv.), this is a standard exercise for the Fubini theorem.

Comment: Thanks, it's been a while since I've studied calculus, and I'm trying to remember stuff!!

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
U(r) = \int_r^d su(s)\,ds.
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\int_l^d \int_r^d su(s)\,ds\,dr &=
\int_l^d U(r)\,dr\\
&= dU(d) - lU(l) - \int_l^d rU'(r)\,dr\\
&= -l\int_l^d su(s)\,ds + \int_l^d r^2u(r)\,dl\\
&= \int_l^d r(r-l)u(r)\,dr
\end{align*}